# How to find the column on which the table is organized in netezza?

Tags: netezza

I have created a table in Netezza as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE sample
( col1 int,
col2 int,
col3 int,
col4 int )
DISTRIBUTE ON HASH (col1,col2,col3)
ORGANIZE ON (col2);
```

After creation of table I want to query the database to find on which column the table is **"organized on"**. As the above table is organized on **"col2"**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find a which column(s) a table is `organized on` you can use one of the following `system table` queries.

```
select *
from _v_odbc_columns1
where orgseqno is not null
```

or

```
select *
from _v_table_organize_column
```

To Find the column(s) a table is `distributed on`.

```
select tablename, owner, attname as distribution_column
from _v_table_dist_map
```

If the table has no value then the table is distributed on `random`;

Comment: I want to find out on what column a table is "organized on", not "distributed on".

Comment: Sorry about that added the organized bit in the answer.